# c++ Header file and include

Tags: c++, header

I have a question regarding where to #include iosteam and vector? In the main.cpp, header.h or in the memberfunction.cpp? Seems I needed using namespace std in main.cpp but #include< functional > in the header file>. Is there any robust way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simple Rule:
***Include the header file only in those files which need it.***

If your source or header file does not use any constructs defined/declared in the header file then there is no need to include that header. Doing so only brings unnecessary code in to those translation units thereby corrupting the namespace and possibly increasing the compilation time.

Comment: Sounds like a good advice, but misses the point. `#include` statements are put in files. Multiple files make up one translation unit, by convention one .cpp file and multiple .h files. Since the question is where to put the `#include`, specifically differentiating between .cpp and .h files, just saying "in the TU" is effectively saying nothing at all. _All_ C++ code is in a TU, there is nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

For readability reasons you want to include headers only in those translation units using them. So in a source code not using at all `std::vector` template you would not `#include <vector>`, hence you would put that include before your own `#include "myheader.h"`

However, you may want to decrease compilation time by pre-compiling the header.
As I explain [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108), precompiled headers with GCC works only if all your program has one single header containing all the includes. For that reason you would want to have a single `myheader.h` which is itself including `<vector>` (even for the few compilation units not using it).

Pre-compilation of header files is compiler (and perhaps system) specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vectors, or input/output streams in any way in your `header.h` (for instance, parameters of that type etc.), then it is better to include `iostream` and/or `vector` there. If you use them only internally in your `memberfunction.cpp`, include it there (it is of no use to the rest of the code).

Comment: Actually, `iostream` is entirely the wrong header for input or output stream parameters. It just defines `std::cout` etc. The stream types themselves are defined in`<istream>` and `<ostream>`. But since you don't need a definition for parameters, just a declaration, use `<iosfwd>`.