# C++ include loop

Tags: c++

I'm a noob in game development and i want to make a simple platform game in C++. The problem is whenI make two classes (Game and Graphics) I can't include Game.h in Graphics.h because I have already included Graphics.h in Game.h. Can anybody help me? 
code:
Game.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Graphics.h"

struct Game {
    Game();

    void init();
    void handle();

    bool running;

    Graphics g;
};
```

Graphics.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL.h>

struct Graphics {
    SDL_Surface* screen;

    void init();

    void rect(SDL_Rect rect, Uint32 color);
    void rect(SDL_Rect rect, int r, int g, int b);
    void rect(int x, int y, int w, int h, Uint32 color);
    void rect(int x, int y, int w, int h, int r, int g, int b);

    void render(Game* game);
};
```

Comment: Avoid as much as possible adding #includes in .h files, put the most used header includes in a common .h file (I call mine <projectname>PCH.h) and include that header at the start of every cpp file and turn on precompiled headers from your IDE or make script. It might seem complicated, but it will save you a lot of trouble in the long run

Comment: no reason really to have one header per class

Comment: Be careful with this common header idea: in my experience, it rapidly grows out of control and you end up with loads of unnecessary dependencies. In general, include what you need, and only what you need.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a forward declaration here:

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H_ // portable include guards
#define GRAPHICS_H_

#include <SDL.h>

class Game; // forward declaration. Exactly the same as struct Game.

struct Graphics 
{
  // as before
};

#endif
```

because `Graphics` doesn't require the definition of `Game`. You will most likely need to include `Game.h` in the implementation file of `Graphics`.

See related post: [**When to use forward declaration?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)

Comment: I think it's better to be more consistent and use `struct Game;`.

Comment: @KennyTM Possibly. It is not the kind of thing I worry about. I added a comment.

Comment: Nitpick: isn't postfixing the all-caps guard macro with an underscore technically UB? That should be `GRAPHICS_H` instead IIRC.

Comment: @H2CO3 I will have a look. I think post-fixing is OK, double underscores bad, leading underscores followed by a capital letter bad. But I could have missed one out.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, double-underscores are definitively a big no-no :)

Comment: @H2CO3 and any leading underscores, in the global namespace. But trailing underscores look OK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 1):

You could have a single header merging both `Game.h` and `Graphic.h`; there is no reason to have one header per class.

If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (then compile with `g++ -Wall -g`), an advantage of having only one header for the entire project is the ability to [precompile your header](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108).