# Using precompiled headers in gcc

Tags: gcc, precompiled-headers

I am investigating using precompiled headers to reduce our compile times.

I have read the documentaiton on the subject here:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html, where I read the following:

> Only one precompiled header can be used in a particular compilation.

On the project whose build time I would like to improve, there are often very Long lists of includes.  The above leads me to Think that to get the most performance improvements, I would have to make a collection of common includes, put them into a single Header file, compile and include that Header file.

On the other hand, I prefer to list my dependancies in particular file explicitly, so I would be inclined to include first the precompiled Header, followed by the Manual list of actual Header files.

I have two questions related to this:

1. Is my analysis and approach correct?  Have I interpreted the statement correctly?
2. Doing this, I will use this file (say stdafx.h) in many places, thereby including files I don't need.  I would like to explicitly list my dependencies however, for code documentation purposes.
   Where I to do something like the following:

   ```
   #ifdef USE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS 
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #else
   #include "dep1.h"
   #include "dep2.h"
   #endif
   ```

   I could periodically run a build without pre-compiled headers to check if all my dependencis are listed.  This is a bit clunky however.  Does anyone have a better solution?

If anyone has Information to help us obtain better results in our Investigation, I am happy to hear them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCC and Precompiled Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437955/gcc-and-precompiled-headers); see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108) still relevant for GCC 4.9

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, your observation is absolutely fine!
   You `"would have to make a collection of common includes, put them into a single Header file, compile and include that Header file"`. This common header file is generally named as `stdafx.h` (although you can name it anything you want!)
2. I am afraid I don't really understand this part of the question.

**EDIT :**

Do you also want the standard headers (like `iostream`, `map`, `vector`, etc.) to be included as dependencies in the code documentation?

Generally this must be a **NO**. Hence, you must include only those header files in `stdafx.h` which are not under your control (i.e., [1] standard language includes [2] includes from dependent modules (mostly exposed interface headers)). Rest all includes (whose source is in the current project/module) must be explicitly included in each header file wherever required, and not put in the pre-compiled `stdafx.h`.

Comment: Thanks for your info.  I made an edit which I hope clarifies the second question.

Answer (score 0):

> The above leads me to Think that to get the most Performance
>   improvements, I would have to make a collection of common
>   includes, put them into a single Header file, compile and
>   include that Header file.

Yes, this observation is correct: You put most (all?) includes in one single header file, which is then precompiled.

Which, in turn, means that...

- any compilation *without* the aid of that header being *precompiled* will take *ages*;
- you are relying on naming conventions or other means (documentation?) to make the information link between things referenced in your individual translation unit and their declaration.

---

I don't much like precompiled headers for those reasons...