# What can be compiled faster? Source and header for each method, or anything in one single file?

Tags: c++, compilation, nvcc

I am writing a compiler that generates C++ code at the end. I am currently wondering what is compiling faster.

First notes about the compiler:

1. I don't have any classes\structs, they are optimized inside the functions.
2. I don't include anything like `#include <vector>`, when I have to use functions such as `printf` from libraries then I manually put prototype. (The compiler do it manually.)

I have two options:

Option #1:

```
//.h
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int function( /* parameters */ );
//.cpp
int function( /* parameters */ ) {
    // code
}
```

Every function has it's own source and header.
Advantages:

1. I can make the compiler comment out the includes that includes file that are included before it. For example if `#include "B.h"`'s content is included in `#include "A.h"` then I will can make it comment out the line `#include "B.h"`. (Saves file reads.)
2. I can recognize unchanged methods/functions/files (When I regenerate my code and it can find exact files from before.) and recycle their object files. (Saves object compiling.)

Option #2:

```
int function( /* parameters */ );
int function2( /* parameters */ );
int function3( /* parameters */ );
// ...
int function( /* parameters */ ) {
    // code
}
// ...
```

All functions are once defined (those prototypes at the top) and compiled in that single file.

Advantages:

1. Single sequential read from the disk. (No hierarchy of including and multiple including from different objects.)
2. Single object to compile, excluding libraries.

At single glance the looks like option #1 is faster, but some folks said they tried the second and it gave their project a boost in compiling time. They didn't compare both options, and didn't gave any proof for it.

Can I get explanation for which one is faster rather than benchmarks?

Comment: Benchmark and find out. Anything else is mostly speculation.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I am sure someone can "give word" but why option is faster than the other, and not just benchmark.

Comment: option 3: implement [modules](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4214.pdf)

Comment: @Bolov: you might be right, but then it is not (yet) standard C++

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It won't be, I think some knowledge about compiling non-CFG code can give a lot of hints about which one is faster. I know abit about it, but I still can't decide. (Both of them almost equally for me in theory.)

Comment: _"I don't have any classes\structs, they are optimized inside the functions."_ Eh? Can you explain how refusing to use data types constitutes "optimisation"?

Comment: _"I don't include anything like #include <vector>, when I have to use functions such as printf from libraries then I manually put prototype"_ Heavens why?!?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is off-topic :), but whatever. I have things such as `string` and sometimes they don't come in allocation of memory of `struct { uint c; char *d; }`, they sometimes come as only `char *d` of that struct, or sometimes they are inlined in some way and etc. (It's optimizations across functions without inlining them.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am compiling CUDA in it, I don't need `<vector>` and etc, and so I want to improve compiling time I need to sit and write my own APIs. (Which is not a lot of work I think)

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: At least include the C headers if you use the functions from the C headers. Declaring that stuff yourself is the path to ruin.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit NVCC Compiler is quiet slow. I just do it once anyway, the compiler manages it by itself. (Define a prototype for functions it uses.) My compiler is mostly for computing, a lot of functions are redundant for me.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: What kind of compiler are you coding? What kind of source language?  Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't want to make my question too specific, I want it to help future readers too. I am not sure what to add. My compiler is optimizating sequential code to parallel and then compile it with CUDA (helps?). It takes C# code parses and generating code. You I think I should add those?

Answer (score 2):

C++ is known to be slow to be compiled, notably because standard C++ headers (e.g. `<vector>`, `<map>` or other standard containers) are bringing a *lot* of C++ code (and tokens) thru *internal* headers.

Are your `#include`-d headers machine generated, or are they all common to your runtime? You might consider having a *single* header and pre-compile it (assuming a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108). Then you need to have only one single `#include` at top of every generated C++ file.

BTW, I am not sure that C++ is a good target language for some compiler. Generating C code (perhaps using [Boehm's GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/), like [Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/) does) is probably more relevant. Generating C++ code makes sense when you want to fit into some existing API, like I am doing in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) fitting into [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) internals, and then I don't generate much code using C++ standard templates.

At last, when you generate C (and even more when generating *genuine* C++) you really want the C or C++ compiler to optimize the generated C or C++ code. Parsing time of the generated code does not matter than much (you might try [-ftime-report](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html) option to measure where is `g++` taking time). Newest GCC 5.1 has [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/JIT) which might interest you.

Comment: It would still eliminate the re-including of headers across different `.cpp`s, but it doesn't eliminate the need to link large number of objects.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important factors is the ability to compile in parallel. As each Translation Unit is compiled in a sequential fashion (at least logically), there is limited opportunity for parallelization if you feed the C++ compiler just one big file.

The balancing force, as pointed out, is the startup cost of each compilation. You've got multiple CPU cores incurring the same startup cost.

As a result, parallelization stops being a win when adding an extra Translation Unit incurs more overhead cost than you save by using that extra core.

Comment: But after that you have to link all of those objects that you compiled, which you can't do in parallel. I think one big object will make the linkage faster. (?) I am starting to think that only benchmark will help here.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: Modern linkers use function-level linking anyway, one big object still contains as many functions.