# Is compiling with C++11 way slower than with C++98?

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, c++98

I wanted to switch my project settings from C++98 to C++11 but I am quite skeptical because of the additional compile time.

My (quite big) project is about 800 files and the project is generated with cmake. In XCode with C++98 setting it compiles in roughly 15min on a i7 4GHz machine (ssd hard-disk, 16GB ram).

When switching to C++11 it takes about 25min (On Windows with Visual Studio 2013 it is even worse - nearly double the time!)

I don't know, something has to be completely wrong in my project setup or with my files, because no one is talking about additional compile times with C++11.

And yes I am using forward declarations, pimpl idioms, even tried double include guards and I removed a lot of template stuff that I don't need anymore thanks to C++11 (so compiling should be even faster, but it's not - it's slower!)

Is compiling with C++11 way slower than with C++98? And why is no one talking about this?

Comment: If we *ever* get modules, that will hopefully solve these problems...

Comment: @Default: I don't see anything there. gcc had support for the old concept of concepts. so what...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question has no general answer, it is a matter of implementations.

Some compilers are faster than others. Phoronix claims that [Zapcc is faster](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=New-Zapcc-Clang-Benchmarks) than its competitors (but I have no idea, I never heard of `zapcc`  before).

I would guess that, for the *same* compiler, compiling C++11 style could be slower than compiling C++03 style (because C++11 introduced extra "syntax overloading" and `auto`, and feature like move constructors which might need extra support)

C++11 is known to be slow at compilation, in particular because standard headers (like `<map>` or `<vector>` ....) are bringing lots of material (and probably more in C++11 than in C++03).

For example, the following `e.cc` file (just two *standard* includes!):

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
```

When compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 -C -E e.cc | wc -l` I am getting 41870 preprocessed lines, when compiling with `g++ -std=c++03 -C -E e.cc | wc -l`  I am getting 15598 lines, both with [GCC 5.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/), on Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64.

You might use precompiled headers (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108)), and you could consider having not too small translation units (e.g. have your `*.cc` files contain a few thousands lines each, not a few dozens lines each).

Since `cmake`  is generating `Makefile`-s for `make`, you might try a parallel build with `make -j`

Comment: Is your last stence supposed to start with "C++11", or just "C++"? As it stands (C++11), it seems to contradict the rest of the answer.

Comment: I won't be surprised if C++11 `<vector>`  is bigger than C++03 `<vector>`

Comment: It turned out that a "clever" precompiled headers indeed helped to get back to normal compiling times. So kudos will go to this post. Thanks a lot! +1