# How does #include work in C++?

Tags: c++, include

If a library is included in a class header and then this header is included in another class do I have to include the library again?

For example:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include<someLibrary.h>

class A{
  ...
}

#endif
```

Then another class includes the A.h header

```
#include<A.h>   //include class A
class B{
   ...
}
```

Do I have to include the "someLibrary.h" in class B?

Comment: Does `B` use anything from `<someLibrary.h>` (i.e. directly and not via `A`)? If so, then yes, "include what you use" - it makes the codebase more robust to inclusion changes.

Comment: a Youtuber told that the compiler will copy and paste the content of a .h file and paste it to your .cpp file.  in this case, you can see if you need to include your stuff or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, `#include`s are transitive.

However, if your second file itself uses symbols from *someLibrary*, it's good style to re-include the header. That way you're not "hoping and praying" that you never remove the intermediate include. Your codebase will be more robust if every source file `#include`s everything that it directly needs. Header guards prevent this from being a wasteful policy.

Answer (score 11):

The [*preprocessor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) `#include` directive does exactly what the name implies, it actually *includes* the file at the place of the directive.

Simple example: Lets say we have to files, first a header file named `a.h`

```
// Our class
class A
{
    // Stuff for the class
};
// End of the class
```

Then a source file `a.cpp`:

```
// Include header file
#include "a.h"
// Header file included

int main()
{
    // Code
}
```

The preprocessor generates a *single* file looking like

```
// Include header file
// Our class
class A
{
    // Stuff for the class
};
// End of the class
// Header file included

int main()
{
    // Code
}
```

This inclusion is recursive, so if a header file is including another header file, that other header file will also be included.

The source file generated by the preprocessor is called a [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) and is what the compiler actually sees.

---

The above is a simplification on how a modern preprocessor works, and while it can be run separately to create a preprocessed source file, it's more common that the preprocessor is part of the compiler to streamline the parsing process.

---

You should also note that the terminology you use is not correct. A library can (and usually do) have one or more header files, which are used when compiling your source code. A library then often (but not always) contain a special library file that is *linked* with the object files created by the compiler.

A library that has no linker library is called a *header only* library.

Answer (score 5):

You don't include classes or libraries, you just include headers, and that is a *textual* operation (a bit like a copy & paste done by the preprocessor).

Read more about the [C/C++ preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), and the [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

You can ask your compiler to show you the preprocessed form of your source file `foo.cc`, e.g. with `g++ -Wall -C -E foo.cc` (it will spills on *stdout* the preprocessed form)

For a small project (e.g. less than 200KLOC), having just one single common header file included by all your translation units is sensible (and I believe that having many small header files is bad habit, so I usually put more than one class definition per header file). BTW, that (single header file) approach is friendly for [precompiled headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108). Some people prefer to have several of their own `#include`-d subheaders in that single header.

Notice that most C++ standard headers (like `<map>` or `<vector>`....) bring a lot of text, so you don't want to have tiny compilation units (on my Linux system, `#include <vector>` is dragging more than ten thousand lines, so having only a few dozen of your source code lines after is inefficient for the compiler)

Also notice that C++ class definitions usually have lots of inlined member functions (and you practically want to give the body of that inlined function in the same header file). So C++ header code tends to be quite big...

<sup>(some people prefer to break a single header file in many subheaders, which are always included together)</sup>

Comment: _"For a small project (e.g. less than 200KLOC), having just one single common header file included by all your translation units is sensible"_ o.O

Comment: @PreferenceBean: what does your `o.O` means above?

Comment: _"that (single header file) approach is friendly for precompiled headers"_ While technically true, the idiomatic approach to precompiled headers (or so I thought, anyway) is not to let them contaminate your codebase but to instead [conditionally] include the behemothic header using command-line arguments (and let header guards elide the actual `#include`s in your code). This allows you to keep all the PCH logic in your build system where it belongs :)