# How to include precompiled .h.gch headers using g++

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, g++

Suppose I have A.h, A.cpp, B.h and B.h.gch (I have downloaded B from Internet)

How can I compile my code (and create an executable) ?

I have an error when I do

```
g++ -c B.h.gch
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: `g++: warning: B.h.gch: linker input file unused because linking not done`

It's a warning but the .o is not generated.

Comment: Well how do you compile in the first place?

Comment: I usually do `g++ -c sources.cpp` and then, `g++ -o executable sources.o` but I've never encountered a .h.gch before and Google can't help me for now. (Sorry if my english is bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can practically have only one single precompiled header `myheader.h` and quite often that single header is including other ones. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108) for more.

You compile that C++ header with `g++ -c myheader.h` (and other relevant options, notably `-O` , `-g`, `-Wall` , `-I`*dirname* ...; they should be the same as for your object files). In practice you should have a `Makefile` and use [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) (run once `make -p` to understand the builtin rules). The `CXXFLAGS` there should be used both for object files and for the precompiled header.

You don't change any `#include` directive (but in practice all your `*.cc` or `*.cpp` files should have only one).

Read also the [Precompiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-)