# -fno-inline and compilation time

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

I'm working on big project most files are longer than 7000 lines. If I'm using -fno-inline option compilation time going down 3 times. 
Actual numbers:
w/o -fno-inline - 340 sec
w/  -fno-inline ~ 115 sec

I didn't find anything about -fno-inline impact on compilation performance. **Is there any explanation to this ?**

Some background:

- I use MACROSes pretty extensively (for logging purposes)
- There is one global Exception try / catch block inherited from old code (need to rework this piece)
- There are few try/catch blocks inside, mostly to catch exceptions from stof/stoi

I tested compilation time with and w/o (-pipe, -O0 to -O3, -g / no -g, -ggdb / no ggdb). Nothing brings compilation time so down as -fno-inline.

Comment: It'll reduce compilation time but it will also reduce run-time performance.

Comment: Why does compilation time matter to you? Are you compiling in parallel several translation units (e.g. using `make -j` or `ninja`)? On which operating system are you compiling? How big is your entire project (milions of lines in hundreds of files?)?

Comment: You could pass [the `-ftime-report` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html) to `g++` to understand better where the compiler is spending its time. However, disabling inlining will lower significantly the run-time performance of your executable.

Comment: "most files are longer than 7000 lines". Run away and don't look back.

Comment: @n.m: have you noticed that `#include <vector>` expands to more than 15KLOC  (at least on Linux, GCC8) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this is actually a pretty good indicator of the sad state of C++. Perhaps modules will change it.

Comment: @n.m: I agree with your comment (that C++ is in sad state). I am less optimistic than you are regarding its future.

Comment: Thank you Basil and n.m.
I want to reduce compilation time due to waiting about 5 mins for every compilation cycle is waste of time. make -j  doesn't help if I have issue with single file file compilation. Looks like I need to refactor single file to multiple. 
Includes are more or less optimal in the project.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on big project most files are longer than 7000 lines.

That is a bit quite big. You might (I am not sure) win a bit of compilation time by avoiding files bigger than 5KLOC (by splitting large C++ files, bigger than 8KLOC, in several ones), and by compiling *in parallel* several translation units at the same time (using [`make -j`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html) or [`ninja`](http://ninja-build.org/)). This requires some refactoring work. On the other hand, with genuine C++, don't have too small files (because standard container headers like `<vector>` could include many thousands lines; you might also consider [having](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108) a precompiled header). Pragmatically 3KLOC to 7KLOC per C++ source file is a nice trade-off in practice.

Use the [`-ftime-report` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html) to `g++` to get a detailed timing of each compilation phase (or passes). You may need to understand the internals of GCC to decipher the obtained table.

> I didn't find anything about -fno-inline impact on compilation performance. Is there any explanation to this ?

[Inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) happens *several times* inside GCC. It generally works on some [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html#GIMPLE) or [SSA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Tree-SSA.html) internal representation. Of course, inlining is improving the runtime performance of your program. By disabling it, you could lose 50% of speed in your executable (and perhaps even more, since inline member functions such as [getters and setters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) are extensively used in C++, notably in standard [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) templates).

FWIW, my old [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) web pages (GCC MELT is now a dead project) have several [slides](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/docum.html) and reference explaining GCC internals, and I am just writing right now (october 2018) the *draft* of a technical report on [bismon](http://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (funded now by the [CHARIOT](http://chariotproject.eu/) H2020 project); that [draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-doc.pdf) happens to have a section §1.3.2 explaining some interesting GCC optimizations.

See also CppCon 2017 talk: [Matt Godbolt “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)